# Running Multiple Instance of Windows Form Application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, multiple-instances

I decided to create a chat application for that I need the single form to be run 2 times (i.e.) I need to view the same Form as two different instances while running it... Is it possible to achieve it.

Note: I dont need it to be done in any of the events. Whenever I run my program 2 instances has to be run.

Comment: If you can show the relevant section of your code we can provide more meaningful answers.

Comment: I just started it and stuck with this problem... which code ur expecting...?

Answer (score 4):

Two solutions:

- Just build your executable and run as many instances of it as you required.
- Use more complex solution that utilizes the [Application.Run Method (ApplicationContext)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157901.aspx). See the simplified MSDN example below.

  ```
  class MyApplicationContext : ApplicationContext
  {
      private int formCount;
      private Form1 form1;
      private Form1 form2;

      private MyApplicationContext()
      {
          formCount = 0;

          // Create both application forms and handle the Closed event 
          // to know when both forms are closed.
          form1 = new Form1();
          form1.Closed += new EventHandler(OnFormClosed);
          formCount++;

          form2 = new Form1();
          form2.Closed += new EventHandler(OnFormClosed);
          formCount++;

          // Show both forms.
          form1.Show();
          form2.Show();
      }

      private void OnFormClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
          // When a form is closed, decrement the count of open forms. 

          // When the count gets to 0, exit the app by calling 
          // ExitThread().
          formCount--;
          if (formCount == 0)
              ExitThread();
      }

      [STAThread]
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {

          // Create the MyApplicationContext, that derives from ApplicationContext, 
          // that manages when the application should exit.

          MyApplicationContext context = new MyApplicationContext();

          // Run the application with the specific context. It will exit when 
          // all forms are closed.
          Application.Run(context);
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: I think this is actually the answer the question wants.

Comment: How can I use ApplicationContext in another class in button event as when user press button a new form will opened or a reopened form is shown??

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can easily create multiple instance of the same form.  For example:

```
new ChatWindowForm.Show();
```

Also see the [`Control.Show()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.show.aspx) method documentation.

Comment: war should I Call this function, in Contructor (or) where ?

Comment: You'd call this in whatever event is responsible for launching a new form - in this case I'm guessing it would be a chat window. If that's part of a button click you could put it inside the click handler. Please edit your question to include some of your current code.